# Return when find variable

Tags: javascript, function

I want return result which variable is available that page. How i can write true function ?

```js
function variation() {
    var variationControl = document.querySelectorAll(".type-label.subtype-square.selected")[0].innerText;
    var doubleVariation = document.querySelector(".type-label.subtype-square.selected");
    var singleVariation = document.querySelector("div.row > div > div > div.col-md-3.product-summary-fixed > div > div > div > p:nth-child(1)");
    if(variationControl == null){
    return "Single Variation";
  } else {
    return doubleVariation.innerText;
  }
}
```

[image: function variation]

Comment: `[0]?.innerText;`

Comment: [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `if(variationControl == null){` will never work. Either `variationControl` is a string or you will get the error in your image.

Comment: @Ifaruki this is very useful thank you very much. But i will use this code in google tag manager and gtm is reported me: "This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2020 mode or better: Optional chaining".

Answer (score 1):

Probably should go with something like this:

```js
function variation() {
    var variationControl = document.querySelector(".type-label.subtype-square.selected");
    var singleVariation = document.querySelector("div.row > div > div > div.col-md-3.product-summary-fixed > div > div > div > p:nth-child(1)");
    if (variationControl === null || variationControl.innerText === ""){
      return "Single Variation";
    } else {
      return variationControl.innerText;
    }
}
```

Comment: `variationControl` and `doubleVariation` are selecting the same element. Checking for `variationControl` yet returning `doubleVariation` is very confusing to read/maintain.

Comment: Modified. Thanks.